# Laravel 5.2 view set to public folder

Tags: angularjs, laravel, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

I am trying to make my routes access to public folder as i am trying to use laravel as api and angular as frontend. I have changed the view file from config folder from

```
    'paths' => [
    realpath(base_path('resources/views')),
    ],
```

To

```
    'paths' => [
    realpath(base_path('public/views')),
],
```

in my public folder i have created a views folder and placed a file called test.html
Now

```
Route::get('/',function(){

return view('test.html');

});
```

it shows error

```
    in FileViewFinder.php line 137
at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('test.html', array('C:\xampp\htdocs\customer_portal\public\views')) in FileViewFinder.php line 79
at FileViewFinder->find('test.html') in Factory.php line 165
at Factory->make('test.html', array(), array()) in helpers.php line 779
at view('test.html') in routes.php line 36
at RouteServiceProvider->{closure}()
```

Do you know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Please do not edit a solution into your question. Instead, post it as a separate answer below. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that U use return view('test.html') on html file! Its wrong, view should be use for php blade templates. Instead return conent of your file (below code I copy-paste from my project FilesController):

```
use Response;
...

public function downloadFile(Request $request)
{

    ...

    return Response::download(path_to_your_file, download_file_name);

}
```

and in `routes.php` file instead of `Route::get('/',function(){...`  put:

```
Route::get('/', 'FilesController@downloadFile');
```